# VIrtual network

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox, network-manager

I want to impliment pfsense to the local network. So before that I have to test it in a virtual environment, say couple of virtual-machines in an Ubuntu host using virtual box and one pf-sense machine which act as a router. Only the pf-sense machine will have real LAN access (for internet), and for all the local VMs ip will be provided by the pf-sense.

Problem is in VB which network interface have to be used for the virtual machines and the pf-sense. For pf-sense I can use bridged adapter for one network interface to get connected to the real LAN. But what will be the other network interface which is only used to communicate to only the LAN machines?

Answer (score 1):

On pfsense VM set

```
1st network adapter to NAT
2nd network adapter to internal
```

all other machines network adapters set to

```
internal
```

here is my video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPWrbBl9EAA)

Answer (score 1):

The "WAN" on pfsense is right to be the bridge adapter, for other VMs and the second interface of pfsense VM use "Internal Netwok", in the picture below I name the Internal Network vswitch as "Secure DMZ" off course you can give your own, and all VMs behind the Pfsense have to be attached to that Vswitch in order to access internet trough pfsense.
Last but not least, you have to disable the block of privates subnet from the WAN interface in pfsense, if you don't external traffic from private subnet will all blocked.

[image]